# Reference Alphabetical Appendix

Tags: cross-referencing, appendix, alphabet

I am using alphabetical headings and page numbers for my appendices. Now, when I refer to them in main text, I would also like to see the letter. However, as of now it shows me a number. How to fix this? See MWE below.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Main}
Please look at Appendix \ref{sec:appendixa}.
\clearpage
\section*{Appendix A} \label{sec:appendixa}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Hi. You don't use alphabetic page numbers, which would be called with `\pagenumbering{Alph}`, but still Arabic with `arabic`/`\arabic`.  And the alphabetical 'counter' of your sections is manually added by hand using an unumbered section command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully clear what you want to achieve. But from your MWE I guess:

1. You want alphabetic numbered sections in the appendix part.
2. You want the word 'Appendix' in front of the alphabetic counter.
3. You want the pagenumber in the appendix to consist of the current appendixletter and the pagenumber in Arabic numbers (A1, for example)

All can be achieved with the following code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\appendixsection}{ m }{
    \renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{Appendix\ \csname the##1\endcsname\quad}
    \section{#1}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Main}

Please look at Appendix \ref{sec:appendixa} on page \pageref{sec:appendixa}.

\clearpage

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\appendixsection{}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thesection\arabic{page}}

\label{sec:appendixa}

\clearpage
\appendixsection{More Appended Stuff}

\end{document}
```

I defined a command `\appendixsection` which puts the word 'Appendix' in front of the alphabetic counter for sections. Just call it with an empty argument to get your wanted output. If you use the argument, you can print an addition to the appendix section title.

Of course, if you now add a second appendix section, the pagenumber will change to `Bx`, where `x` is the current number of the appendix part. If you want another style for the pagenumbering, please clarify your wishes.

Comment: What I wanted was "Please look at Appendix A" instead of "Please look at Appendix A". But your code does that! Thanks